# How to import Job_Applications.csv file in the training recruiting app using the new Data Import Wizard?

Tags: data-import-wizard

I recently started with self Salesforce training and am doing the standard **Recruting app**. I am currently on the **Version 9.2, August 2016** version of PDF and the Salesforce release of my developer account is **Spring 17**. Now here's he problem I am facing.

In *Chapter 6: Expanding the Simple App Using Relationships*, in the final stages, we have to import 3 CSV files using the **Data Import Wizard** which we download from the Salesforce website as *RecruitingApp-9.0.zip* from the website. Unfortunately, these files were last updated in January 2015 and the Data Import wizard has apparently changed quite a bit now. While I could import the first two files by troubleshooting and making some changes, I am simply unable to import the *Job_Applications.csv* file (Page 144). I cannot find any way to mention the following instructions into the Data Import Wizard

```
Specify Relationships    Which user field...? None  
                         Which lookup fields...? Candidate, Position

Define Lookup Matching   Which field on Candidate...? Email (External ID)
                         Which field on Position...? Position Title
```

Because of this, I am unable to map the email and Position Title fields as they are to be fetched from the parent object of the lookup relationship. I simply don't get the options to map these fields in mapping options.  How do I proceed in this case or how can I work around this issue? I have tried using Data Loader too but to no impact! At the current stage, I can actually add those records manually but that's not an option I want to follow.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading the data you need to define email id in candidate object as unique.
Then you will get an option Email(External ID) in data import wizard. Rest process is same as the pdf.

The instruction Define Lookup Matching: 
Which field on Candidate...? Email(External ID)
Which field on Position...? Position Title

Wants you to be able to upload data on basis of External IDs but as per current version, the pdf is a bit outdated. Selecting only Candidate Name in Candidate lookup field does not resolve the lookup relation completely. In the case of position look up, as position name is a standard field it gets mapped easily.

Step 1) Setup>Find>Object>Candidate>Email>Edit>Do not allow duplicate values
Step 2) Setup>Data Import Wizard>Custom Objects>Job Applications>Add new records>Candidate Field>Email(External ID)>Position Field>Position Name>Next>Map Position object with Position and Candidate with Candidate>Next and VIOLA.